# What is the liquid used in the 2014 M3 charge air cooler?

Tags: bmw, intercooler

I'm familiar with the use of air intercoolers/charge air coolers to cool the intake charge (usually on turbocharged engines). But this BMW engine seems to use liquid to cool the intake charge. Which liquid is used (water?) and how exactly is it managed? Certainly looks pretty nifty.

[image]

Comment: It either it shares coolant from the radiator system or it has it own separate water supply....http://f80.bimmerpost.com/forums/showthread.php?t=983790

Comment: http://www.modine.com/web/en/liquidcooled-chargeair-coolers-9.htm#.VyS-m0y4nuo

Comment: I'm sure it's the same 50/50 mix as is used in the radiator, but is its own separate system. The coolant in the engine would be too heat soaked to do the job, so from an engineering standpoint you'd want it separate. The reason to use antifreeze in it is for the same reasons you'd use it in your engine: anti-corrosion; anti-boil; anti-freeze. Gives the coolant a much broader range than if it was just water all by itself.

Comment: To add to what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said: If you buy it from the dealership then its made of Unicorn Rainbows. But if you buy it from a regular euro parts store its coolant.

Comment: @timbo  It does look nifty.  Not so familiar with BMW's but love looking at pics of what's under the hood.

Comment: It's water, from a container (usually in the boot) which is sprayed into the inlet manifold.  Sort of like a permanent seafoam type arrangement.

Comment: Answered in related question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/35968/675

Answer (score 2):

If it's anything like the BMW M4 GTS, it's water.  Purely and simply water atomised into the inlet tract.

[This](https://jalopnik.com/how-the-absurdly-expensive-bmw-m4-gts-water-injection-w-1760175847) link contains more information.

Answer (score 0):

That is coolant running through the charge air cooler (inter cooler). Many engines just use the same coolant and water pump from the normal engine cooling system to circulate the coolant mixture through the charge air cooler. Since we are on the topic of BMW I will note that the N63 V8 uses a separate cooling system and pump for its charge air cooling.

Comment: The M3 definitely does not inject coolant from the cooling system into the inlet manifold.